# Selecting fontsize in B5 book

Tags: fontsize, paper-size, book-design

I used

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
```

to make A4 paper size book and then join two A4 pages to one A4 page landscape (that created two A5 papers). The fontsize after joining two pages into one was quiet suitable.

I would like to use B5 paper size

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twocolumn]{book}
```

but now I would like to specify directly the fontsize, that would be suitable and comparable to the fontsize that would be created by joining two B4 pages into one B4 page.

Comment: Not quite sure, but if I understand correctly, you've produced A4 pages, then scaled them down to A5 for printing. You'll probably get nicer typography by starting at A5, then printing them 2-up without any scaling.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that would be better solution to 2-up two B5 (originally A5) pages. The question is what fontsize should I use for B5 paper size. Using extsize  \documentclass[8pt,b5paper,twocolumn]{extbook} I can use 8pt - but the fontsize is still too big.

Comment: I think you may have to tweak the font sizes manually (which I'm afraid I'm not qualified to help you with). But I also think that at these sorts of font size you're going to have readability problems anyway, unless it's a reference work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using extsizes class `extbook` is possible to set fontsize to 8pt, that is sufficiantly small font on B5 paper size.

```
 \documentclass[8pt,b5paper,twocolumn]{extbook}
```